# Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2013 missing the Azure Storage node

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2013, server-explorer

I have Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 installed on my computer.  I recently installed the Azure 2.5 SDK.  In my old Visual Studio 2012, in Server Explorer, I see a Storage node like this:

```
Azure
  - Cloud Services
  - HDInsight
  - Notification Hubs
  - Service Bus
  - Storage              <-----  That's what I want
  - Virtual Machines
  - Web Sites
```

But in Visual Studio 2013, I see this:

```
Azure
  - HDInsight
  - Mobile Services
  - Notification Hubs
  - SQL Databases
  - Websites
```

I'm not sure if Microsoft intentionally reduced the choices, or I have something installed wrong, but I have the VS 2013 update 4 installed so I think I'm up to date.

I haven't found an easy way to update my CDN files on Azure without that Storage node.  Anyone have any explanation for my missing Storage node?

Comment: I have VS 2013 (Update 4) and I can see storage node. Looks like your installation got messed up somehow. May I suggest that you reinstall/repair SDK installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this issue on my system by

1. In Programs/Uninstall: select 'Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013…'
2. Click 'Repair' 
    Wait 3-4 min and that's done, no need to restart your pc

Comment: I don't have 'Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio' in my Programs and Features window.  My Server Explorer -> Azure node has several subnodes, none of which are Storage.

Comment: @Nicolas Guinet I Repaired , even restarted my PC but SQL databases option is not visible

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee405484.aspx

You should download the Azure Tools for your Visual Studio.
is under the .Net section.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved it on my machine by:

1. going here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40893
2. Click the Download button
3. Select **WindowsAzureStorageTools.msi** and **WindowsAzureTools.vs120.msi**
4. Click "Next" and then Run, etc.